# WiX 3.11.2 and .NET 4.7.2 COM+ applications

Tags: .net-4.0, wix3.11

I am trying to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 developed COM+ component using WiX 3.11.2.

And it fails doing this with the following error in the log:

> Action 14:38:48: RegisterComPlusAssemblies. Registering COM+
>   components
>
> RegisterComPlusAssemblies: DLL: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\WiXTestingComPlusApplication\NET472ServicedComponent.dll
>
> ComPlusInstallExecute:  ExceptionInfo: Code='0',
>   Source='System.EnterpriseServices', Description='Failed to load
>   assembly 'c:\program files
>   (x86)\wixtestingcomplusapplication\net472servicedcomponent.dll'.',
>   HelpFile='', HelpContext='0'
>
> ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80020009:
>   Failed to invoke RegistrationHelper.InstallAssembly() method
>
> ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80020009: Failed to register .NET
>   assembly
>
> ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80020009: Failed to register
>   assembly, key: ComPlusAssembly_NET472ServicedComponent
>
> ComPlusInstallExecute:  Error 0x80020009: Failed to register
>   assemblies CustomAction ComPlusInstallExecute returned actual error
>   code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened
>   inside sandbox)

In the binding log, I can see that there was an attempt to load the .NET 4.7.2 based COM+ component assembly using .NET 2.0 runtime:

> Assembly Binder Log Entry  (11/15/2019 @ 2:38:49 PM)
>
> The operation failed.
>
> Bind result: hr = 0x8013101b. No description available.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\**v2.0.50727**\mscorwks.dll
>
> Running under executable  C:\Windows\syswow64\MsiExec.exe
>
> --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>
> LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = c:\program files (x86)\wixtestingcomplusapplication\net472servicedcomponent.dll
>
> LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/syswow64/
>
> LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>
> LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
>
> LOG: Cache Base = NULL
>
> LOG: AppName = NULL
>
> Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>
> ===
>
> LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
>
> WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
>
> LOG: No application configuration file found.
>
> LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>
> LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/program files (x86)/wixtestingcomplusapplication/net472servicedcomponent.dll.
>
> LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: c:\program files (x86)\wixtestingcomplusapplication\net472servicedcomponent.dll
>
> LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase. ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x8013101b).
>
> ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = **0x8013101b**). Probing terminated.

The error code means **COR_E_NEWER_RUNTIME**.

The custom action from WiX Toolset Extentions uses native DLL custom action to register the COM+ application.

And it looks like it is not using the latest version of the .NET Framework.
Is there any way I could control it?

And of course it works fine if ServicedComponent is using .NET Framework 2.0.

I have created a small demo for the problem [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoOdv1sqkAI9ioJ2eeowOqLI110IMw?e=Z0MZeJ).

**UPDATE - added WiX wxs file contents**

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="NET20ServicedComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="Component_NET20ServicedComponent" Guid="{49682A46-A29D-45EE-863A-C0F9935CDB35}" KeyPath="yes">
            <File Id="File_NET20ServicedComponent.dll" Source="$(var.NET20ServicedComponent.TargetPath)"/>
            <File Id="File_NET20ServicedComponent.tlb" Source="$(var.NET20ServicedComponent.TargetDir)NET20ServicedComponent.tlb"/>

            <complus:ComPlusApplication Id="ComPlusApplication_NET20ServicedComponent"
                                                                    Name="NET20ServicedComponent"
                                                                    Description="Testing NET20ServicedComponent">
                <complus:ComPlusAssembly Id="ComPlusAssembly_NET20ServicedComponent"
                                                                 DllPathFromGAC="no"
                                                               DllPath="[#File_NET20ServicedComponent.dll]"
                                                               TlbPath="[#File_NET20ServicedComponent.tlb]"
                                                                 Type=".net"/>
            </complus:ComPlusApplication>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <ComponentGroup Id="NET472ServicedComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="Component_NET472ServicedComponent" Guid="{885DB376-CF66-4C46-AF14-4436C6B76EB5}" KeyPath="yes">
            <File Id="File_NET472ServicedComponent.dll" Source="$(var.NET472ServicedComponent.TargetPath)"/>
            <File Id="File_NET472ServicedComponent.tlb" Source="$(var.NET472ServicedComponent.TargetDir)NET472ServicedComponent.tlb"/>

            <complus:ComPlusApplication Id="ComPlusApplication_NET472ServicedComponent"
                                                                    Name="NET472ServicedComponent"
                                                                    Description="Testing NET472ServicedComponent">
                <complus:ComPlusAssembly Id="ComPlusAssembly_NET472ServicedComponent"
                                                                 DllPathFromGAC="no"
                                                               DllPath="[#File_NET472ServicedComponent.dll]"
                                                               TlbPath="[#File_NET472ServicedComponent.tlb]"
                                                                 Type=".net"/>
            </complus:ComPlusApplication>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
```